# Remove file name in a URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can i remove a file name in url with mod_rewrite.

ex: `searchpage-some+search.html` in to `some+search.html`

This is my .htaccess code code.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /searchpage\.php\?search=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^searchpage\.php$ /searchpage-search-%2.html? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule searchpage-search-(.*)\.html$ searchpage.php?search=$1 [L]
```

This is for a search form that uses $_GET request. This works well only thing is that i want to remove the file name. I would really appreciated if anyone can help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have `searchpage-some+search.html` but in your htaccess you are actually rewriting it to `searchpage-search-some+search.html`.

But to remove the `searchpage-search` from links, just remove `searchpage-search-` from the RewriteRule. Your htaccess would be something like

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /searchpage\.php\?search=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^searchpage\.php$ /%2.html? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ searchpage.php?search=$1 [L]
```